# How should you design both sides of a diary page to avoid sewing/stitching/punching the content?

Tags: print-design, print-production, book

I'm using Illustrator to design a page which have content on both sides. I've created 2 artboards of same size for this. It will be used in the middle of a blank diary as an *advertisement*. Now I'm new to this stuff.

[image]

Let's assume this is the page that I'm designing:

[image]
[image]

Roughly, on front side, I need more space on left edge of page. On back side, I need space on right edge since when we will fold the page, the right side of back page will become inner. I don't know exact words to describe this. But hope you got my point.

Now, I don't want to ask what margins should I leave on each sides. I just want to know if this is the right ratio approach and my thinking is right?

Comment: You have your pages laid out the wrong way round compared to your mockup. The larger gutter then goes between the two. Knowing how large it needs to be depends on how many pages there will be per section & which page yours will be. I'd ask the printer/bindery, as your pages may actually end up on a much larger folded sheet. (I can't provide an actual answer to this - I used to print books but I've never had to lay them out myself.)

Comment: Once again you should absolutely confirm these things with the printing company, but yes, that should work.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's not mockup. That's real artboard.

Comment: And I haven't laid them out.

Comment: Those 2 artboards are 2 sides of a single paper.

Comment: ah, I wasn't aware you were planning double-sided, I thought you had an insert leaf. tbh, if you are only supplying a single double-sided page to be included as just a part of a larger print run, then whoever makes up the final pages will be responsible for pagination & gutter stepping to fit their finished product. You should ask them how they want your pages.